# When upload new image in storage/app/public directory after laravel 8 not showing this image in website page

Tags: laravel

when i uploaded new image in storage directory then every time this image not showing in website even path are same and other images are showing properly. And when i fully project upload again in live then working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7WHf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPUyj.png)

Comment: Can you navigate to network tap and see whether any error occurred in that request

Comment: RIN THIS `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: after removed working image but still this image showing. I have tried Artisan::call('cache:clear'); but still showing this image